# HQL unexpected AST node: {vector} when using an ArrayList as parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Searched and found a lot of questions about this but nothing for my particular case.  I am getting an error on my HQL query, here is the code:

```
String year = "";
ArrayList<String> loc = new ArrayList<>();

// Set above variables to something here
//
query = em.createQuery("select distinct x.fmlName, " +
        "                               x.email " +
        "                   from person x " +
        "                  where x.year = :selYear " +
        "                    and ((:selLoc = 'ALL') " +
        "                        or x.loc IN (:selLoc)) ");

query.setParameter("selYear", year);
query.setParameter("selLoc", loc);

return query.getResultList();
```

And here is the error:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: {vector}
```

I am relatively new to Hibernate and am struggling with this since the error message isn't super helpful.  Any ideas?

Comment: What is `:selLoc = 'ALL'` ? List == value ? makes no sense

Comment: @DN1 if the parameter that comes in is 'ALL' then dont do anything, if it is not 'ALL' then hit the OR clause and use the list

Comment: You cannot have a List equality with a String value. End of. Even if the List has 1 value.

Comment: @DN1 so maybe I need to use a new parameter in that case, and set it equal to the first value in my original list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem here :

```
"                    and ((:selLoc = 'ALL') "
//----------------------------^
```

This should be the name of a field, or a String so :

- If `:selLoc` should be the name of a field this is not possible, to use it like this, because when you use `setPrameter("field", "fieldname")`, your query should look like this `'fieldname' = 'ALL'` and this not correct because fields should not be between 2 quotes
- but it seems you are using a list and compare it with a string and this is also not correct

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `(:selLoc)` to `:selLoc`. When using Java `List` in HQL like this:

`... WHERE x.loc IN :myList`

the `myList` must not be in parentheses.

2. Also, this is wrong `(:selLoc = 'ALL')`